# finding roots to an equation - binary search

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-search

Trying to identify the problem for Python 3.5.  The program is to find the root of an equation, once two x-values are found that surround the zero (one yielding positive and the other negative).  I think I have an infinite loop:

```
from math import *

def getFunction():
    func = input("Enter your function: f(x) = ")
    return func

def getHighLow():
    hi = eval(input("Enter an x-value that gives a positive result: "))
    lo = eval(input("Enter an x-value that gives a negative result: "))
    return hi, lo

def findTheZero(func, hi, lo):
    delta = eval(input("How close to zero to you want to get? Within 0.01 Enter a value: "))
    x = (hi + lo) / 2
    while abs(eval(func)) > delta:
        if x > 0:
            hi = x
            x = (hi + lo) / 2
        else:
            lo = x
            x = (hi + lo)/2
    return x

def main():
   function = getFunction()
   hi, lo = getHighLow()
   print(findTheZero(function, hi, lo))

main()
```

Comment: `if x > 0:` is incorrect. func(x) should be tested instead, i.e. `if eval(func) > 0:`. As was already said `eval` is really really dangerous.

Comment: If this is not for school then you can save yourself the trouble of writing this. See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.bisect.html.

Comment: Woah there... Don't use eval for this! Eval and Exec are dangerous functions. Kinda like os.quit...